# MongoDB - reference a document within a document

Tags: mongodb

I want to reference a parent document within an embedded document, is this possible? I want to do this because I have users who have images who have comments... so i want a comment to be by a specific user.
This is my structure:

```
db.site_users.insert([
{
    email: 'pbrown@hotmail.co.uk',
    password: 
    fullName: 'Peter Brown',
    images: [
        {
            title: 'Here is a sample title',
            location: 'here is a sample location',
            imageURLs: ['http://exmaple.com/uploads/39873874.jpg', 'http://example.com/uploads/7844656.jpg'],
            tags: ['tagone', 'tagtwo'],
            comments: [
                {
                    site_users_id: '',
                    comment: 'Yes definately agree with you',
                }
             ]
         }
}])
```

It is the site_users_id within the comment that I am not sure about, I thought this could be the object ID of another user that exists within the same document. is this the correct way to reference another user? or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes that seems about right.

Comment: Yes, you can use the _id for referencing (be it an ObjectId or not). Nevertheless, be careful because the potential for those user documents to grow too large is quite hight (embedded images and respective nested comments).